# Error in running "npm run dev:ssr" in Angular

Tags: angular, metaprogramming

I am following [this](https://angular.io/guide/universal) Angular Universal tutorial. I get an error when I execute this command:

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

This is the terminal window verbage:

```
Compiled successfully.
C:\Users\Denise\Do
cuments\projects\blogangulareight\node_modules\aws-amplify-angular\dist\src\components\authenticator\authentica
tor\authenticator.factory.js:15
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, } from '@angula
r/core';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/mod
ules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.aws-amplify-angular/dist/src/components/authenticator/authenticator/authenticator.factory (C:\Users\Denise\Documents\projects\blogangulareight\dist\blogangulareight-server\main.js:10726:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Denise\Documents\projects\blogangulareight\dist\blogangulareight-server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/components/auth/auth.component.ngfactory.js (C:\Users\Denise\Documents\projects\blogangulareight\dist\blogangulareight-server\main.js:8982
:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Denise\Documents\projects\blogangulareight\dist\blogangulareight-server\main.js:20:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54811
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

When I view the main.js file there is no syntax error

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it?